# VB.NET - How to format text boxes so they divide the text into chunks of n letters?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, textbox, string-formatting

I have two text boxes, that can only contain capital letters, and a variable where I store an unsigned integer. Let's say for instance 5. How can I make it so that my  TextBoxes that contain random text are split into groups of 5 letter?

For example: `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`

Becomes: `ABCDE FGHIJ KLMNO PQRST UVWXY Z`

I need this to be done in real time in case the text is replaced by the user. I also cannot use multiple text boxes that allow n characters each as the text I'm supposed to format can be indefinitely long.

Comment: use multiple textboxes which only allow 5 characters each.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?626118-License-Key-Serial-Code-TextBox

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach for every time the `Textbox.Text` changes:

```
Private Sub Textbox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Textbox1.TextChanged
    Dim sentence As String = Textbox1.Text
    Dim pairedChars as Integer = 5

    If pairedChars <= sentence.Length Then
        'First remove all spaces from the last time
        sentence.Replace(" ", "")

        'Add spaces at every 5th place in the string
        For i = 1 to (sentence.Length) / pairedChars 
            sentence = sentence.Insert(i * pairedChars + (i - 1), " ")
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```